# Editing Startup Programs in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

I recently installed [Samsung All Share](http://www.samsung.com/global/allshare/pcsw/) on my PC. I observed it always started up when I switched the PC on. I went into msconfig and unchecked the box for this particular software. Inspite  of that it still seems to run every time I boot. I have also seen the startup folder located in C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs. It isnt there either. 
Also just as an addon, when I go to C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp I see only two programs. But when I view it by pressing the window key and All programs I see many others. Any Idea why?(Samsung All Share isnt one of them).

Comment: This question is likely a duplicate. For managing startup entries throughout Windows, I recommend [Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) by Microsoft.

Comment: Great Tool. I found that the program was checked in the registry. But how does this happen. I have specifcally disabled it in the startup . Then how does it still remain checked ?

Comment: There may be another startup entry/process that is checking for it, and re-adding it if necessary.

Comment: But once i boot i observe that it is still unchecked .